# How to save a Nested Object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
const checkAuth = require("../../../util/checkAuth");
const { Post } = require("../../../models/post");
const { Like } = require("../../../models/like");

const upvoteComment = async (_, { username, postID, commentID }, context) => {
  checkAuth(context);
  /*  TODO Securety concern one Person can upvote the same post via post request */
  const like = new Like({
    username: username,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });
  const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: postID });
  const findComment = (post) => {
    for (let i = 0; post.comments.length > i; i++) {
      if (post.comments[i]._id == commentID) {
        return i;
      }`enter code here`
    }
  };
  const index = findComment(post);
  console.log(index, "index");
  console.log(post.comments[0]);
  post.comments[index].likes.push(like);

  post.save();

  return like;
};

module.exports = { upvoteComment };
```

I am trying to save a  Like which I have modelled into a Comment on a Post. First I fetch the Post from my Mongo DB database, then I loop through the comments to find the comment with the id of the comment that was liked and I push the new like object into that comments likes array but when I save the like will not be saved... Does this have something to do with nesting?

So i changed the Code to this

```
const checkAuth = require("../../../util/checkAuth");
const { Post } = require("../../../models/post");
const { Like } = require("../../../models/like");

const upvoteComment = async (_, { username, postID, commentID }, context) => {
  checkAuth(context);
  /*  TODO Securety concern one Person can upvote the same post via post request */
  const like = new Like({
    username: username,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });
  const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: postID });
  console.log(post.comments);
  const findComment = (post) => {
    for (let i = 0; post.comments.length > i; i++) {
      if (post.comments[i]._id == commentID) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
  const index = findComment(post);

  /*   console.log(index, "index");
  console.log(post.comments[index]);
 */
  if (index !== -1) {
    post.comments[index].likes.push(username);
    post.comments[index].likes.push(like);
    post.title="this title will be saved"
    const res = await post.save();
    console.log("likes on the server: ", res.comments[index].likes);
  }
  const savedPost = await Post.findOne({ _id: postID });
  console.log("likes on Database: ", savedPost.comments[index].likes);

  return like;
};

module.exports = { upvoteComment };
```

and the console will return this:

```
likes on the server:  [
  'username',
  {
    _id: 6081838453f4aa1ff4db6b5e,
    username: 'username',
    createdAt: 2021-04-22T14:09:08.817Z
  }
]
likes on Database:  []
```

This does indeed change the title of the post so I have concluded that mongoDB sees the `post.comment[i].likes` field as uneditable even though i have declared it as an Array... The type of item doesnt matter for this either as i have tested it in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once hope it works for you.

```
  const upvoteComment = async (_, { username, postID, commentID }, context) => {
  checkAuth(context);
  /*  TODO Securety concern one Person can upvote the same post via post request */
  const like = new Like({
    username: username,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });
  const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: postID });
  const findComment = (post) => {
    for (let i = 0; post.comments.length > i; i++) {
      if (post.comments[i]._id == commentID) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
  const index = findComment(post);
  console.log(index, "index");
  console.log(post.comments[0]);
  if(index !== -1)
    post.comments[index].likes.push(like);

  await post.save();

  return like;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
post.comments[i].likes.push({
  username: "johndoe",
  createdAt: new Date(),
});
```

instead of using `new Like({...})`

By the way, you should use `findIndex` for conciseness and clarity:

```
...
const i = post.comments.findIndex(comment => comment._id === commentID);
post.comments[i].likes.push(like);
await post.save();
...
```

Comment: await is not the problem on this one I have tried that already and I also tied saving another title for my post and it worked so the bug must be in the difference between the title property and the like... but thank you I will use the findIndex method instead=)

Answer (score 0):

So the Problem lied within my Schema definiotion and was a simple Typo I apologize to everyone that tried to wrap their head around this...